# Can a List<> be cast to a DataModel

Tags: jsf, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to do the following:

```
public String createByMarcas() {
    items = (DataModel) ejbFacade.findByMarcas(current.getIdMarca().getId());
    updateCurrentItem();
    return "List";
}

public List<Modelos> findByMarcas(int idMarca){
    return em.createQuery("SELECT id, descripcion FROM Modelos WHERE id_marca ="+idMarca+"").getResultList();
}
```

But I keep getting this expection:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5070)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:4968)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4756)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
 at $Proxy347.findByMarcas(Unknown Source)
 at controladores.__EJB31_Generated__ModelosFacade__Intf____Bean__.findByMarcas(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone give a hand please?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the function `setWrapperData()` of the JSF `DataModel`.

Example:

```
DataModel dataModel;
List list;

list = em.createQuery("Select b from Book b").getResultList();
dataModel.setWrapperData(list);
```

Comment: This code works fine for me, for converting a `List<>` to `DataModel`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most obvious answer to your question is no. You query retuns a `java.util.List`, which is unrelated to a JSF  `DataModel`, assuming that that's what you're casting to. I know nothing about JSF, but it seems that there is a [ListDataModel](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html) which can be used to wrap a List, so that might help in your case.

Comment: Yes I'm casting to a JSF DataModel, I will try the ListDataModel but do you know anything about this exception? em is  EntityManager, if it helps shouldn't it work?

Comment: I don't know your setup, but from what I know about JPA, the EJBException is thrown when a method cannot be completed normally due to an exception. In your case it should wrap a ClassCastException, I would expect. Is the stacktrace you supplied complete?

Comment: no Is not complete it actaully quite big, should I paste it here?

Comment: You need `new ListDataModel(ejbFacade.findByMarcas(current.getIdMarca().getId()));`.

Comment: Thanks Balus but still throws same excecption

Comment: The stacktrace is completely unrelated to the question "Can List be casted to DataModel?". This exception is already thrown long before the attempt to cast has been taken place. Reframe your question. It's an EJB problem, not a casting problem.